# Self contained JAR with Tomcat and JNDI placeholders

Tags: spring, tomcat7, jndi, self-contained, tomcat7-maven-plugin

I'm in the process of transitioning the legacy Spring 3.2.8 application from WAR deployment to self-contained JAR. I'm using *tomcat7-maven-plugin* to create an executable JAR:

`mvn install tomcat7:exec-war`

Since the application uses JNDI placeholders, it obviously fails to run without them defined. In Tomcat installation following placeholders are defined: (`conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mediaagent" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mediaagent" username="user" password="password"/>
<Environment name="hibernate/dialect" type="java.lang.String" value="PostgreSQL" />
```

The `context.xml` which is packaged in WAR, has following placeholder references:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mediaagent" global="jdbc/mediaagent" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="hibernate/dialect" global="hibernate/dialect" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Finally, these placeholders are used in *applicationContext.xml* in the following way:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/mediaagent"/>
</bean>



    <bean id="dataSourceProperties"
              class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="properties">
                <props>
                ...
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.${dialect}Dialect</prop>
                ...
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

My goal is to extract these settings to separate configuration file which should be placed next to the self-contained JAR, preferably *properties* file as in Spring Boot. There also should be the possibility to inject them with JNDI as with WAR file. What is the most elegant way achieve it?

Comment: _like_ boot or _with_  boot ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @Marged: *like* Spring Boot. We use Spring 3.2.8 so I cannot use Spring Boot.

Comment: Why not simply upgrade Spring, generally it is a drop in replacement, which would give you Spring Boot , which in turn saves you reinventing the wheel. I would suggest not to use JNDI but simply property files and let Spring configure the datasource. The `${dialect}` can also be set as a system variable instead of JNDI `-Ddialect=Oracle`. The datasource replace with a spring configured instead of JNDI datasource.